# running coded ui test by test agent

Tags: coded-ui-tests, automated-tests

I have a requirement to run coded ui test cases in different machines, I got to know that I can run the coded UI test without Visual studio by test agents, Anyone knows how to do that,and is there any licence issue with Microsoft test agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Test Controller on one machine (it can be your main development machine) and than install Test Agents on all machines you want to run your tests on and connect Test Agents to your Test Controller. Installing Test Agents does not require purchasing additional VS license (actually it does not require VS at all). Then in Visual Studio you need to create .testsettings file where you define on what machines you want to run your tests ("Role" section in .testsettings file)
Read more about:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd648127.aspx

Comment: ok thanks, I download latest version of test agent from above link , http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38186. using this test agent in windows machine without VS generates any licence issue?